# Any news about sticky cursor while scrolling in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, scrolling, cursor

This is just a remake of the question [Don't change the cursor position when scrolling in Emacs](https://superuser.com/q/527356/308428): it is almost six years old so I thought maybe there are some news.

As explained in that question, I want the cursor in Emacs just stay at the location in the text while I scroll (so it becomes invisible if I scroll more than one window height below or above).

I've got an impression from that question that Emacs fans hate this idea, so let me explain that I really, really need it. Here is why: I am running [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) in Emacs. While it is computing something, occasionally I want to return back to contemplate what has been already computed. The cursor follows me, and if at that moment GAP produces output, it will go where the cursor currently is, producing big mess sometimes.

It means that I do not necessarily want to make cursor stay where it was. It would be also OK to force GAP placing output where the cursor was before Emacs moved it away. But I suspect that would be much more difficult to do. If not, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It is not a possible duplicate, actually it is a conscious duplicate, with an additional motivation

Comment: [When a user posts a duplicate but adds “none of the answers there worked”, is it a duplicate?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7497/432690)

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) maybe? Is there a reason you run the tool in an *editor*? The reason may be you want to inject its output in the middle of an existing file. But if you only want to monitor it, keep it simple: `tool > file`, then [`less +F file`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41281/108618), Ctrl+C to be able to navigate back, Shift+F to monitor the growing file again. If you don't want to save to a file (unlikely) and only need the output to be displayed, all you need is a [scrollback buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145050/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski There are lots of things you can run in emacs, I only mentioned GAP as one example. The same applies to [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/), [PARI-GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), TeX and several others - you can use it as a GUI for various compilers, etc. There are tons of emacs addons for such purposes. People created such things since they are very convenient. I don't think it is wise to avoid them only because of a cursor problem.

Comment: Concerning your previous comment - I absolutely think that it is wrong to ask a question anew if it does not have satisfactory answers. In my case I provide additional serious reason; without it, maybe that question could create impression of a whim.